# Compare all values in one column with all values in another column and return indexes

Tags: numpy, pandas, compare

I am interested in comparing all values from 1 dataframe column with all values from a 2nd column and then generating a list or a subset df with values from a 3rd column that is adjacent to the 1st column hits. Hopefully this example will explain it better:

For a simplified example, say I generate the following pandas dataframe:

```
fake_df=pd.DataFrame({'m':[100,120,101,200,201,501,350,420,525,500],
                  'n':[10.0,11.0,10.2,1.0,2.0,1.1,3.0,1.0,2.0,1.0],
                  'mod':[101.001,121.001,102.001,201.001,202.001,502.001,351.001,421.001,526.001,501.001]})
print fake_df
```

What I am interested in doing is finding all values in column 'm' that are within 0.1 of any value in
column 'mod' and return the values in column 'n' that correspond to the column 'm' hits. So for the above code, the return would be: 
10.2, 2.0, 1.1 
(since 101,201 and 501 all have close hits in column 'mod').

I have found ways to compare across the same row, but not like above. Is there a way to do this in pandas without extensive loops?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know such method in pandas, but when you extend your scope to include
numpy, two options come to mind.

### Easy/Expensive Method

If you can live with N**2 memory overhead, you can do numpy broadcasting to
find out all "adjacent" elements in one step:

```
In [25]: fake_df=pd.DataFrame({'m':[100,120,101,200,201,501,350,420,525,500],
                  'n':[10.0,11.0,10.2,1.0,2.0,1.1,3.0,1.0,2.0,1.0],
                  'mod':[101.001,121.001,102.001,201.001,202.001,502.001,351.001,421.001,526.001,501.001]})

In [26]: mvals = fake_df['m'].values

In [27]: modvals = fake_df['mod'].values

In [28]: is_close = np.abs(mvals - modvals[:, np.newaxis]) <= 0.1; is_close.astype(int)
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

As we care only about 'mod' values that have adjacent 'm's, aggregate over axis=0:

```
In [29]: is_close.any(axis=0).astype(int)
Out[29]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Or otherwise

```
In [30]: fake_df.ix[is_close.any(axis=0), 'n']
Out[30]: 
2    10.2
4     2.0
5     1.1
Name: n, dtype: float64
```

### Efficient/Complex Method

To find adjacent elements in less than O(N**2) without any hashing/rounding
tricks, you have to do some sorting:

```
In [103]: modvals_sorted = np.sort(modvals)

In [104]: next_indices = np.searchsorted(modvals_sorted, mvals)
```

You have indices of next elements, but they may point beyond the original
array, so you need a one extra `NaN` at the end to avoid `IndexError`.  Same
logic applies to previous elements which are `next_indices - 1`: to avoid
indexing before the first element we must prepend one `NaN`, too.  Note the `+ 1` that arises because one of `NaN` has been added to the beginning.

```
In [105]: modvals_sorted_plus = np.r_[np.nan, modvals_sorted, np.nan]

In [106]: nexts = modvals_sorted_plus[next_indices + 1]

In [107]: prevs = modvals_sorted_plus[(next_indices - 1) + 1]
```

Now it's trivial.  Note that we already have `prevs <= mvals <= nexts`, so we
don't need to use `np.abs`.  Also, all missing elements are `NaN` and comparing with them results in `False` that doesn't alter the result of `any` operation.

```
In [108]: adjacent = np.c_[prevs, mvals, nexts]; adjacent
Out[108]: 
array([[     nan,  100.   ,  101.001],
       [ 102.001,  120.   ,  121.001],
       [     nan,  101.   ,  101.001],
       [ 121.001,  200.   ,  201.001],
       [ 121.001,  201.   ,  201.001],
       [ 421.001,  501.   ,  501.001],
       [ 202.001,  350.   ,  351.001],
       [ 351.001,  420.   ,  421.001],
       [ 502.001,  525.   ,  526.001],
       [ 421.001,  500.   ,  501.001]])

In [109]: (np.diff(adjacent, axis=1) <= 0.1).any(axis=1)
Out[109]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [110]: mask = (np.diff(adjacent, axis=1) <= 0.1).any(axis=1)

In [112]: fake_df.ix[mask, 'n']
Out[112]: 
2    10.2
4     2.0
5     1.1
Name: n, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
# I assume all arrays involved to be or to be converted to numpy arrays
import numpy as np
m = np.array([100,120,101,200,201,501,350,420,525,500])
n = np.array([10.0,11.0,10.2,1.0,2.0,1.1,3.0,1.0,2.0,1.0])
mod = np.array([101.001,121.001,102.001,201.001,202.001,502.001,351.001,421.001,526.001,501.001])

res = []
# for each entry in mod, look in m for "close" values
for i in range(len(mod)):
    # for each hit, store entry from n in result list
    res.extend(n[np.fabs(mod[i]-m)<=0.1])
# cast result to numpy array
res = np.array(res)
print res
```

The output is

```
[ 10.2   2.    1.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll be making of numpy (imported as np) which pandas uses under the hood. [np.isclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) returns a boolean indexer: for each value of the iterable, there's a `True` or `False` value corresponding to the value `m` being within `atol` of each value of `df["mod"]`.

```
>>> for i, m in df["m"].iteritems():
...     indices = np.isclose(m, df["mod"], atol=0.1)
...     if any(indices):
...         print df["n"][i]
```

Using the DataFrame you gave produces the output:

```
10.2
2.0
1.1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because your comparison between `m` and `mod` does only compare `m[i]` vs. `mod[i]`. The question asks for comparison of `m[i]` vs. `mod[j]` for all `i` in `range(len(m))` and `j` in `range(len(mod))`.

Comment: Right you are, thanks for pointing that out. Edited so that I answer the question, but it looks like @immerrr has the way to go :)